# Plotting anomalies in a simple isolation forest example using Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am creating a very simple model that can detect anomalies in time series data, which for my case are arbitrary temperature readings (to detect high temperatures).My data set is as follows

[image: 1]

```
no | temp
1  | 36.5
2  | 39.8
3  | 37.4
4  | 40.2
5  | 40.8
```

As evident, there are 2 spikes or anomalies (highlighted in bold). The isolationForest model easily detects this anomalies and the dataframe `df['anomalies']` returns the index location of the anomalies.

Here's the code fragment that reports back the anomalies (locations in the dataset)

```
df['anomaly']=model.predict(df[['temp']])
anomaly=df.loc[df['anomaly']==-1]
print("Anomalies are detected at these positions")
anomaly_index=list(anomaly.index)
print(anomaly_index)
```

The above code then predicts the anomalies in the form of **Index Locations** (within dataset) e.g. [43, 26, 126]

Based on that, I have two issues that I am unable to resolve:

1. How to get the values from `anomaly_index` index locations. (For example, after detection of these temperature anomalies, I would like to pull the respective temperature values (such as 39.8 & 40.8) so that I can further perform actions on it.
2. I can plot the dataframes for original values, but I would like to overlay/super-impose the outliers or anomalies in the graph (for example, all the temperature readings from the dataset, alongwith these 2 anomalies).

I tried all possible ways, but due to my lack of skills in python, I am stuck at this problem.
Could anyone please help?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these step:

Step-1: Define a threshold value, if any value coming above that will be considered as Anomalies.

Step-2: Compare all value with threshold and store store it.

You can try this

```
     THRESHOLD = 39
     df['threshold'] = THRESHOLD
     df['anomaly'] = df.temp > df.threshold
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I can actually compare/count the outliers/anomalies. What I don't understand is to how to Fetch the respective Temperature values (temperature spikes from dataset). And, how to plot temperatures and anomalies on the same plot, so that it is easy to highlight the outliers.